# How to pause signal output in gnuradio?

Tags: python, gnuradio

I have transmitted a piece of binary data with "preamble", "valid bits", and CRC32. I want him to transmit 1S once and rest 1S once, how can I achieve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kX5k.png)